# Interior lighting circuit flashing when connecting inverter driven led stripe

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, pwm

I am currently doing some work on my car and I've installed a led stripe which is powered by a 12V inverter circuit ( details of that are unknown ). Now when I connect this to the rest of the interior lighting, everything starts to flicker.

The maximum power consumption of the stripe is 60mA, so I don't believe that the power requirements aren't met. I think that the inverter introduces some kind of noise into the supply grid, which causes some spikes.

The interior light cirucit emits a PWM Voltage which varies from 7-12V ( I haven't measured the frequency yet.

My question is, if it is possible to somehow decouple the PWM from the interior light circuit from the inverter power supply, while mentaining the same output. Maybe a voltage follower?

Comment: Why do you need an inverter to power an LED strip? It's a DC load, right?

Comment: I don't know the exact translation in English. It's probably some kind of neon ledstrip. Btw, the issue is only observed when engine is on and not with power from the battery.. Very strange.

Comment: This is pretty odd! If there is a problem due to input current harmonics causing the alternator voltage to drop and rise all the time, your original lights should still be operating normally (from battery or alternator voltages) because they should have been tested for such scenario. I would suggest trying a capacitor on the inverter's input to decouple high frequency current demands. Or, although pretty unrealistic considering the power requirements, you could be triggering current limitation during very short periods.